# filtering the keys of a python dictionary for all the items of a list

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, key

I am trying to filter the keys of a python dictionary for specific strings.

```
def filterDictionary(filterdata):
    dictionaryToFilter = {'car 1':100,'car 2': 200, 'car 3':300, 'bus 1':1000, 'bus 2':2000, 'bus 3':3000} 
    filterInput =[]
    filterInput = filterdata.split()
    for a in filterInput:
        dictonaryFiltered = {k:v for (k,v) in dictionaryToFilter.items() if a in k}
    return dictonaryFiltered
```

I have come to the point where my code filters the keys for any of the strings of the input, separated by space, but I want to have it filtering for all of them.

For example filterDictionary('ca 1') will return {'car 1': 100, 'bus 1': 1000}
and I want it to return {'car 1': 100} only.

I guess it is done using all(), but I can not figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you *iterate over* `filterInput`, so the dictionary you return only includes checks for the last character, `'1'`, which is in all keys. You need to put `all` and the iteration over `filterInput` **inside** the dictionary comprehension. Also, `dictionaryToFilter` should probably be a second parameter of the function.

Comment: Thank you all for the examples and the explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def filter_dictionary(filter_data):
    dictionary_to_filter = {'car 1': 100, 'car 2': 200, 'car 3': 300, 'bus 1': 1000, 'bus 2': 2000, 'bus 3': 3000}
    spl = filter_data.split()
    dictionary_filtered = {k: v for (k, v) in dictionary_to_filter.items() if all(a in k for a in spl)}
    return dictionary_filtered

print(filter_dictionary('ca 1') )
{'car 1': 100}
```

You need to check that `all` the substrings are in the dict key.

You are checking if either `1`  **or**  `ca` are in each key not both so you get `'bus 1'` because `"1"` is obviously a substring.

`if all(a in k for a in spl)` checks that every substring from our split input string is equal to or a  substring of the key string.

I also changed your code to use lowercase and separate words using underscores which makes you code more readable and in line with the [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a string contains every character in a
substring with

```
all(character in somestring for character in substring)
```

so,

```
def filterDictionary(filterdata):
    dictionaryToFilter = {'car 1': 100, 'car 2': 200, 'car 3': 300,
                          'bus 1': 1000, 'bus 2': 2000, 'bus 3': 3000}
    return {k: v for (k, v) in dictionaryToFilter.items()
            if all(character in k for character in filterdata)}

print(filterDictionary("cr1"))
{'car 1': 100}
```